# 'str_replace' and 'strtr' not working inside plugin

Tags: customization

My goal is simple:

Take a string like this -->  'https://www.secondarysite.com/subpage'

And turn it into this --> 'https://www.primarysite.com/secondarysite/subpage'

Sounds simple enough right?

In a standalone PHP file (i.e. not using WordPress), this code works as expected:

```
function changeThisURL() {
  $current_url = 'https://www.secondarysite.com/subpage';
  $new_url = str_replace("secondarysite.com", "primarysite.com/secondarysite", $current_url);
  echo $new_url;
}
```

It echoes out the changed URL properly.

Now if I drop that same function in a WordPress plugin and call it, it echoes out the value of $current_url before the changes.

I have also tried using 'strtr':

```
function changeThisURL() {
  $current_url = 'https://www.secondarysite.com/subpage';
  $trans = array('secondarysite.com' => 'primarysite.com/secondarysite');
  $new_url = strtr($current_url, $trans);
  echo $new_url;
}
```

The results are the same:  it works perfectly in a standalone PHP file, but inside WordPress it fails and spits out the starting value of $current_url.

Additional info:
* This is a multisite.
* I've found that if I'm using strings that don't contain slashes or periods, everything works fine.

Comment: there is no way it is wp related. you must have some bug in some other part of your ode

Comment: Right sir.  I tracked it down and posted the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark was correct that it was some other code causing the issue.  I tracked it down to a plugin I use during testing: Insert PHP; https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/

There's a line in the plugin's code that's replacing forward slashes.

Anyhow, I ran the same code I was trying yesterday via a shortcode, and everything works as expected.